# Submitting two Forms is possible? asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I have two forms in a single page, and both have a save button respectively.
Whenever I click the other button, I want the changes that I added on the other form to be saved as well.

This is my code:

```
<div id="contentMain">


         @using (Html.BeginForm("ClientLocationSave", "Client", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "clientLocForm" }))
            {
            <input type="hidden" id="clientId" name="clientId" value="@ViewBag.ClientId" />
            <input type="hidden" id="clientLocId" name="clientLocId" value="@clientLocId" /> 

        <h2>
            Client Location @pageAction</h2>
        <div class="main">
            <p>
                <label for="txtName">
                    Name</label>
                <span>
                    <input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" class="validate[required] inputLong" value="@clientLocName" />
                </span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="txtAddress1">
                    Address 1</label>
                <span>
                    <input type="text" id="txtAddress1" name="txtAddress1" class="validate[required] inputLong" value="@addressLine1" />
                </span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="txtAddress2">
                    Address 2</label>
                <span>
                    <input type="text" id="txtAddress2" name="txtAddress2" class="inputLong" value="@addressLine2" />
                </span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="txtCity">
                    City</label>
                <span>
                    <input type="text" id="txtCity" name="txtCity" class="validate[required] inputLong" value="@city" />
                </span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="ddlState">
                    State</label>
                <span>
                    @Html.DropDownList("ddlState", new SelectList(ViewBag.StateList, "ID", "Display_Value", state), "[Please Select]",
                new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    {"class","validate[required] inputLong"}
                })
                </span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="txtZipCode">
                    Zip Code</label>
                <span>
                    <input type="text" id="txtZipCode" name="txtZipCode" class="validate[required,custom[onlyNumberSp],maxSize[20]] inputLong" value="@zipCode" />
                </span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="btnSave" class="styledButton" value="Save" />

    }
 <div class="main">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("ClientLocationContactSave", "Client", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "contactForm" }))
        {
            <input type="hidden" id="clientId" name="clientId" value="@clientId" />
            <input type="hidden" id="clientLoctContactId" name="clientLoctContactId" value="@clientLoctContactId" />
            <input type="hidden" id="clienLocatId" name="clienLocatId" value="@clientLocId" />

            <p>
                <label for="ddlContact">
                    Contact Type</label>
                <span>
                    @Html.DropDownList("ddlContact", new SelectList(ViewBag.ContactType, "ID", "Display_Value", contactTypeLookId), "[Please Select]",
                new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    {"class","validate[required] inputLong"}
                })
                </span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="txtValue">
                    Contact Value</label>
                <span>
                    <input type="text" id="txtValue" name="txtValue" class="validate[required] inputLong"
                        value="" />
                    <p>
                        <label for="chkSaveIsPrimary">
                            Is Primary</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="chkSaveIsPrimary" id="chkSaveIsPrimary" value="true" checked="checked" />
                    </p>
                </span>
            </p> 
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var disableFields = $('#clienLocatId').val();
                    if (disableFields == 0) {
                        $('#disable').attr("hidden", false);
                        $('#txtValue').attr("disabled", true);
                        $('#ddlContact').attr("disabled", true);
                        $('#chkSaveIsPrimary').attr("disabled", true);

                    }
                    else {
                        $('#disable').attr("hidden", true);
                        $('#txtValue').attr("disabled", false);
                        $('#ddlContact').attr("disabled", false);
                        $('#chkSaveIsPrimary').attr("disabled", false);

                    }
                });


            </script>



            <p>
                <span>
                    <input type="submit" id="btnAddLocationContact" name="btnAddLocationContact" class="styledButton"
                        value="Add Contact" />
                </span>
            </p>
        }
    </div>
CONTROLLER:
public ActionResult ClientLocationSave(FormCollection formCollection)
        {
            String msg = String.Empty;
            String newClientLocationId = String.Empty;
            String clientId = formCollection["clientId"];
            String clientLocId = formCollection["clientLocId"];
            String locationName = formCollection["txtName"];
            String address1 = formCollection["txtAddress1"];
            String address2 = formCollection["txtAddress2"];
            String city = formCollection["txtCity"];
            String state = formCollection["ddlState"];
            String zipCode = formCollection["txtZipCode"];

            Client_Location clientLoc = new Client_Location();
            try
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientLocId) || clientLocId == "0")
                {
                    clientLoc.ClientID = Convert.ToInt32(clientId);
                    clientLoc.Name = locationName.Trim();
                    clientLoc.Address_Line1 = address1;
                    clientLoc.Address_Line2 = address2;
                    clientLoc.City = city;
                    clientLoc.State_LookID = Convert.ToInt32(state);
                    clientLoc.ZipCode = zipCode;
                    clientLoc.DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    clientLoc.DateModified = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    clientLoc.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name;
                    clientLoc.ModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name;

                    db.Client_Location.Add(clientLoc);
                }
                else
                {
                    int id = Convert.ToInt32(clientLocId);
                    clientLoc = (from a in db.Client_Location
                                 where a.ID == id
                                 select a).SingleOrDefault();

                    clientLoc.Name = locationName.Trim();
                    clientLoc.Address_Line1 = address1;
                    clientLoc.Address_Line2 = address2;
                    clientLoc.City = city;
                    clientLoc.State_LookID = Convert.ToInt32(state);
                    clientLoc.ZipCode = zipCode;
                    clientLoc.DateModified = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    clientLoc.ModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                msg = "Failed to save";
            }



            db.SaveChanges();
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((msg)))
            { TempData["message"] = "Client Location Saved Successfully."; }
            else if (msg != "")
            { TempData["message"] = msg; }

            newClientLocationId = clientLoc.ID.ToString();

            return RedirectToAction("ClientLocationDetails", new { clientId = clientId, clientLocId = newClientLocationId });

        }
  public ActionResult ClientLocationContactSave(FormCollection formCollection)
        {
            String msg = String.Empty;
            String clientId = formCollection["clientId"];
            String clientLoctContactId = formCollection["clientLoctContactId"];
            String clienLocatId = formCollection["clienLocatId"];
            bool isPrimary = Convert.ToBoolean(formCollection["chkSaveIsPrimary"]);
            String value = formCollection["txtValue"];
            String contactTypeLookId = formCollection["ddlContact"];


            Client_Location_Contact clientLoc = new Client_Location_Contact();
            try
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientLoctContactId) || clientLoctContactId == "0")
                {
                    clientLoc.Client_LocationID = Convert.ToInt32(clienLocatId);
                    clientLoc.Value = value.Trim();
                    clientLoc.IsPrimary = isPrimary;
                    clientLoc.ContactType_LookID = Convert.ToInt32(contactTypeLookId);
                    clientLoc.DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    clientLoc.DateModified = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    clientLoc.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name;
                    clientLoc.ModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name;

                    db.Client_Location_Contact.Add(clientLoc);
                }
                else
                {
                    int id = Convert.ToInt32(clientLoctContactId);
                    clientLoc = (from a in db.Client_Location_Contact
                                 where a.ID == id
                                 select a).SingleOrDefault();

                    clientLoc.Value = value.Trim();
                    clientLoc.IsPrimary = isPrimary;
                    clientLoc.ContactType_LookID = Convert.ToInt32(contactTypeLookId);
                    clientLoc.DateModified = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    clientLoc.ModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                msg = "Failed to save";
            }


            db.SaveChanges();
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((msg)))
            { TempData["message"] = "Contact Saved Successfully."; }
            else if (msg != "")
            { TempData["message"] = msg; }


            ViewBag.clientLoctContactId = clientLoctContactId;
            ViewBag.clienLocatId = clienLocatId;
            return RedirectToAction("ClientLocationDetails", new { clientLocId = clienLocatId, clientId = clientId });
        }
```

Can this be done with jQuery, and if yes - how?

Comment: If you can use a JavaScript solution, you can do both saves via AJAX calls. For no-script HTML I don't think you have an option aside from wrapping everything in a form and submitting it all together...

Comment: You have to make two post requests to two different Actions.

Comment: @WYSIWYG how to make two post request? iam new at this .. thnx

Comment: I think this will help you. 
http://weblogs.asp.net/dfindley/archive/2009/05/31/asp-net-mvc-multiple-buttons-in-the-same-form.aspx
 Have you looked at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials These are Sine Qua non

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets reword your question a little into something more abstract to help you:

You have two paper forms that need to be signed and given to your manager. One has to be given to Fred in HR, another to Wilma in Sales on the other side of the building.

Can you leave your desk and get both signed at once? Of course not. You need to pick one to do first and then go to the second one before finally arriving at your manager with both forms signed.

The same is true for your page, you can bundle it all into one form and submit it to the server, handle the first part, then get some other code to handle the second part, then return the result to the user.

While there is some fancy trickery you can use to get around this, you need to ask yourself why you would want to. If you always save both forms then why bother having two?